# Why declare an interface inside an interface?

Tags: java

This is a simplified version of java.util.Map

```
public interface Map {
    interface Entry{
        int getKey();
    }

    void clear();
}
```

My question is why it is done that way?

How the inner interface should be implemented? Can I just implement the inner one?

Comment: What would be the alternative you'd expect?

Comment: e.g. Why not just declare methods in the outer interface?

Comment: @Ryan: Those are two different types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to be... terribly theoric here... so keep an open mind, please. A separate `Entry` interface would decouple that concept from the context it is meant to. Don't think only about the interface but about its implementations. Take for example the `Entry` inner static class defined in `HashMap`:

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> next;
    final int hash;

    (...)
}
```

This `Entry` class is not intended to be used outside, and the interface it implements represents a service contract meant only for internal use amongst `Map`s, in particular because `Map` is an interface itself and needs a little abstraction to let the particular implementations define the kind of entry that they will use.

Indeed, I bet you're wondering *"Sure, but an entry can be used in many situations, specially when you need a Key - Value pair"*. This is, in fact, true, but I personally agree with the current design decision as it provides everything that is required to implement a `Map` in a single place.

Answer (score 5):

Here `Map` is used also as a namespace. It's because `Entry` does not belong to the global scope - there are many other entities that are `Entries` and are not necessary `Map`'s entries. This indicates that `Entry` represents entries related to the `Map`.